# How to visually verify correlation in a Generalized Linear Model with Binomial Distribution?

Tags: regression, data-visualization, binomial-distribution, statsmodels

I am trying to determine whether my exogenous variables have significant influence over an endogenous variable.

This response variable is a count, so I am using a generalized linear model with a binomial distribution. I run the following code and get the following result:

```
stickers_pct_incorrect_2_reg = sm.GLM(stickers_2[['incorrect_count', 'correct_count']], stickers_2[['q', 'lambd', 'kappa', 'q_sq']], family=sm.families.Binomial())
stickers_pct_incorrect_2_res = stickers_pct_incorrect_2_reg.fit()
stickers_pct_incorrect_3_reg = sm.GLM(stickers_3[['incorrect_count', 'correct_count']], stickers_3[['q', 'kappa', 'lambd', 'q_sq']], family=sm.families.Binomial())
stickers_pct_incorrect_3_res = stickers_pct_incorrect_3_reg.fit()
```

[image]

We see that all the variables are significant, but it seems suspicious to me. Here are the plots:

[image]

As you can see in the center and right plots, the variables `lambd` and `kappa` do not necessarily appear to be in a linear relationship with `incorrect_count` and `correct_count`.

Is this because these simple plots are not able to show this relationship? Do I need to transform the data before making plots that will make the relationship is evident?

I'm expecting to see some strong visual indicator given that the significance is very strong. Or am I using the model incorrectly?

Comment: interesting question. We have plots like ccpr that show the partial relationship (removing effect of other variables) of a variable for OLS. But I don't know what the corresponding plots are for GLM.

Comment: statsmodels GLMResuults has Ceres plot and partial residual plot https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults.html  Maybe one of them applies to show the partial relationship

Comment: Thanks @Josef, I was able to verify this using both plots.